# How to get access to Status Code and Error message in HTTP Response

Tags: angular

Here is my Setup, i have a Angular reactive form which posts Data to a RestAPI to make this happen there is multiple files involved. First one is the apiService where i call the folowing code

```
  post(config: {endpoint: string, useAuthUrl?: boolean, body: any, params?: any, reqOpts?: any}) {
      config = ApiService.initRequestOptionsAndParams(config);
      return this.http.post(this.apiUrl(config.useAuthUrl) + config.endpoint, config.body, config.reqOpts);
  }
```

this file is called by my surveyService file via

```
  quickCreate(survey: Partial<ISurvey>) {
        return this.api.post({endpoint: '/survey', body: survey});
    }
```

and finally i call this from my surveyrequest via

```
 this.surveyRequestService.quickCreate(this.form.value)
      .subscribe(response => {
        console.log('HTTP Response: ' + JSON.stringify(response));
      });
```

there is some more as i intercept the http request and add the x-token as header but that's not of issue here. My problem is all works fine as long as the far end response with a 200 or so, if i get a 400 or 500 the response never makes it into the response but i get the error in console.

[image]

So how can i access this error in my code to check if my post was successful and if not what the error was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass another function in `surveyrequest` where you are subscribing to the actual observable.

```
 this.surveyRequestService.quickCreate(this.form.value)
      .subscribe(response => {
        console.log('HTTP Response: ' + JSON.stringify(response));
      },
      (error) => {
        if(error instanceof HttpErroResponse) {
           // Handle error
           console.log("Status: "+ error.status +", Message: " + error.message);
        }
      });
```

Also, Check [this](https://blog.angularindepth.com/expecting-the-unexpected-best-practices-for-error-handling-in-angular-21c3662ef9e4) to see how to handle errors using [HttpInterceptor](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor).

HTH.